# Made a program to check armstrong number, but can't find out what's wrong with it

Tags: python, debugging, error-handling

This is basically code to check whether the given number is an armstrong number.But I just don't understand why my output does'nt come correctly

```
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
sum = 0
temp = num
while temp > 0:
   digit = temp % 10
   sum += digit * 3
   temp //= 10
if num == sum:
   print(num,"is an Armstrong number")
else:
   print(num,"is not an Armstrong number")
```

The output isn't coming correctly

Answer (score 0):

Your algorithm is wrong. The line:

```
sum += digit * 3
```

...should be...

```
sum += digit ** 3
```

That was clearly your intent. **However**, that only works for 3-digit numbers. A general approach could be implemented thus:

```
from math import log10

def isArmstrong(n):
    _len = int(log10(n)) + 1
    _n = n
    _sum = 0
    while (_n > 0):
        _sum += (_n % 10) ** _len
        _n //= 10
    return _sum == n
```

**Example:**

```
# all values from 1-9 are Armstrong numbers so start from 10
for i in range(10, 1_000_000):
    if isArmstrong(i):
        print(i)
```

**Output:**

```
153
370
371
407
1634
8208
9474
54748
92727
93084
548834
```

Answer (score -1):

Get the total number of digits and apply the [`pow()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow)

```py
num = int(input("Enter a number: "))
num_digits = len(str(num))
sum = 0
temp = num
while temp > 0:
   digit = temp % 10
   sum += pow(digit, num_digits)
   temp //= 10
if num == sum:
   print(num,"is an Armstrong number")
else:
   print(num,"is not an Armstrong number")
```